# SSL to individual database

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to setup an SSL connection to an individual database, or does it have to be done at the instance level?

Answer (score 3):

Connection settings, including encryption, are instance level. Since connections can switch databases at any moment (simply issue an USE statement) it makes no sense at all to have such settings at database level.

Security constrains ('all traffic to and from this DB must be encrypted') often result in splinting the DB into its own instance just to satisfy the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can setup a connection only to the instance of the database (e.g. MySQL) running, hence to all its databases.  I am not aware of any database system that would allow you to connect to one base only.  If you want to limit access to one database then create an user that has right on that database only, and use that identifier to connect to the database instance.

Answer (score 0):

Databases usually (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle) allow you to decide if particular connection to the database server (instance) should be encrypted or not. The database server must be configured to support SSL, and SQL Server may even be configured to require it for all connection: [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316898).

For client connection string to SQL Server, consult e.g. [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879949%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).